# SSO and CA-signed certificates

Tags: single-sign-on, certificates, custom-domain, okta

We are trying to set up SSO with Okta for our prod salesforce instance.

And one of the compliance requirements from our IT/security department is to use only CA-signed certificates, i.e. self-signed certificates are not allowed for production setup.

We've tried already to buy CA-signed certificate (by generating CSR on SF side etc.) via known CA authorities like Entrust, GoDaddy etc., but they all require to confirm ownership of the domain for which you want certificate to be issued, e.g.  **my-app-domain.lightning.force.com**

To do so, they usually suggest one of three options:

1. send email with confirmation code to one of the emails registered with your DNS
2. add some test record to your DNS server config
3. put some file into the web root of your domain instance

All of this seems to be not possible to achieve in case of SF instance, since we don't have direct control over DNS or host machine itself. And we are not using communities or digital experience, and don't have public site configured etc.

But I feel like we are missing something here - there should be an easy way to achive this. Buying  CA-signed certificate is a widely spread practice.

What are we doing wrong? How this can be achieved for SF domain instance? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a Salesforce domain. You can do this with a [custom domain of your own attached to an Experience Cloud site](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_determine_configuration.htm&type=5). SSO between an external identity provider such as Okta and Experience Cloud site will work. You'll need to think about the UX and do some work to route the users back from Experience Cloud site to their original destination.

Comment: @identigral Thanks for the suggestion. Seems like it is a bit of hacky workaround just to let internal employees to authenticate via SSO and Okta into SF prod instance. Can't still believe that there is no normal way of doing this(